# error: package com.android.volley does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to add Volley to my android project in Android Studio. 
I downloaded Volley from git, and added it as a module using the Project Structure tool, as an android library. I fixed the errors regarding the build version an was able to compile with the new module added to my project. I started writing code and the Volley stuff even shows up in my auto complete and the packages were automatically added to my source file.

But when I compile, i get `error: package com.android.volley does not exist`

Does anyone know what my problem is?

here is my project structure:
[image]

here is my apps build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.loop"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.+'
}
```

and settings.gradle:

`include ':app', ':volley'`

Comment: I think you should have a lib dir where your put your jar files

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had to add `compile project(':volley')` to my dependencies under build.gradle

so final code is

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.+'
    compile project(':volley')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley) adding this dependency could help:

```
dependencies {
    ........
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
}
```

It helped me with Android Studio 3.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work..
Add this in last of Build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your dependency

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
```